# Data management in CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Collecting text from multiple sites. 
Currently, obtain four data points. One has multiple commas.
This data point spreads over multiple cells in a datasheet. I am using python 3.6 to collect and write the files.

What can I do to contain all the data in one cell?

I am using

```
       f.write
```

to write all the data point together in one csv.

& how can I have each data point under one specific header?

***Thank you for any help***

Comment: Hello, please be more specific with your question, provide mode code with explanation what and why it is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('file.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow([1,2,3])
```